# JavaScript export 2 functions

Tags: javascript, export, react-redux, material-ui

I'm using React, Redux and now trying to include Material-UI. The Reduct and the Matrial-UI libs are showing example code that has an export at the end.

**Redux**:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(myComponent)
```

**Material-UI**:

```
export default withStyles(styles)(myComponent);
```

When I'm trying to bring both exports together, I have to get rid the default. So I thought it should look like this

**This does not work:**

```
export {
  connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(myComponent),
  withStyles(styles)(myComponent)
}
```

**Error:**

```
"Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected , (120:15)
       export {connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(myComponent)}
                      ^
```

**This doesn't work:**
I tried to name the function, but then the function wasn't called, for some reasons I don't know.

```
import * as myConnect from 'react-redux'
...
export const connect = myConnect.connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(View)
```

I don't know what is happening 'under the hood' so I'm stuck. Any help is appreciated :-)

EDIT
I haven't found a solution yet but I got around the problem. I split the component (myComponent) into an extra file. The design is event better like that, now it distinguishes between pure components and containers.

Answer (score 2):

There is another solution that a lot of people will need at one point to build HOC (Higher order component). I will suggest using Recompose utility (if you are ok to add another package to your project). Here is a [link to great article](https://medium.com/front-end-developers/building-hocs-with-recompose-7debb951d101) about it on medium.

So if I will be writing your code here is how I will write to build HOC:

```
    import compose from 'recompose/compose';

     //...your component code here

    export default compose(withStyles(styles), 
                           connect(mapStateToProps, actions))(myComponent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(myComponent),
  withStyles(styles)(myComponent)
}
```

This isn't a valid object; you're missing the keys.

```
{
    myConnectedComponent: connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(myComponent),
    myStyledComponent: withStyles(styles)(myComponent)  
}
```

Comment: While the OP *could* export an object, named exports probably make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Make them named exports:

```
export const myConnect = connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(myComponent);

export const myStyles = withStyles(styles)(myComponent);
```

Then use named imports:

```
import {myConnect} from './yourscript';
```